# Subspaces of $\mathbb R^3$ connected or not

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers

> Let $V$  be the span of  $(1,1,1) \text{ and } (0,1,1)\in \mathbb R^3$ .Let $u_1=(0,0,1),u_2=(1,1,0),u_3=(1,0,1)$
>
> Which of the following are
>   correct?
>
> 1.$(\mathbb R^3\backslash V)\cup (0,0,0)$ is not connected.
>
> 2.$(\mathbb R^3\backslash V)\cup \{tu_1+(1-t)u_3;0\le t\le 1 \}$ is connected.
>
> 3.$(\mathbb R^3\backslash V)\cup \{tu_1+(1-t)u_2;0\le t\le 1 \}$ is connected.
>
> 4.$(\mathbb R^3\backslash V)\cup \{(t,2t,2t):t\in \mathbb R\}$ is connected.

I think the option $1$ is correct because the said space is a $1$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^3$  but I'm not sure as to how to approach the other $3$ options.

Any hints or lead to the solution is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$V$ is the plane of equation $y=z$.

1. $\mathbb R^3 \setminus V \cup \{(0,0,0)\}$ is path connected. Two points can be joined either by the segment joining them in the space or by two segments joined at the origin. Hence this set is connected as a path connected subset is connected.
2. Is equal to $\mathbb R^3 \setminus V$ as the segment $\{tu_1+(1-t)u_3;0\le t\le 1 \}$ is included in the half space $z > y$. Hence this subset is not connected.

Following the same way, you'll be able to prove that 3. and 4. are path connected hence connected.

Comment: How ? I need those proofs.

Answer (score 1):

By drawing the figure you can easily say that it is actually connected or not connected.
 $V$ is always of the form $V=\{ (a,a+b,a+b)\}$ so from the first option $(0,0,0)$ must belong to any of the connected component of $\mathbb{R}^3-V$ hence $1$ is correct. Now about $3$ the region $\mathbb{R}^3-V$ is connected by the line segment as $(1-t,1-t,t)$ connects the region $\mathbb{R}^3-V$